Mesh Generation and Saving Problem from Point Cloud with Open3D
I have a point cloud that I calculated from some images and I am trying to generate a mesh (3D surface) from this point. I can successfully create the point cloud, but I am having trouble creating a mesh from this cloud and saving the mesh I created. I have shared my full code below.
Libraries I Use:
Open3D
NumPy
Matplotlib
OS
Traceback
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import traceback

def read_point_cloud(file_path):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Dosya bulunamadı: {file_path}")

        if not os.access(file_path, os.R_OK):
            raise PermissionError(f"Dosya erişim izni yok: {file_path}")

        ply = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file_path)
        if ply.is_empty():
            raise ValueError("Nokta bulutu boş veya geçersiz.")

        return ply

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in read_point_cloud: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

def generate_depth_map(points, width, height):
    try:
        depth_map = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float32)
        for point in points:
            x, y, z = point
            u = int(np.clip(x, 0, width - 1))  # Ölçekleme ve sınır kontrolü
            v = int(np.clip(y, 0, height - 1))  # Ölçekleme ve sınır kontrolü
            depth_map[v, u] = z
        return depth_map

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in generate_depth_map: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

def refine_depth_map(depth_map):
    try:
        min_val = np.min(depth_map)
        max_val = np.max(depth_map)
        print(f"Min depth value: {min_val}, Max depth value: {max_val}")
        if max_val > min_val:
            depth_map_normalized = (depth_map - min_val) / (max_val - min_val) * 255
        else:
            depth_map_normalized = np.zeros_like(depth_map)
        depth_map_uint8 = np.clip(depth_map_normalized, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
        return depth_map_uint8

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in refine_depth_map: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

def plot_depth_map(depth_map):
    try:
        plt.imshow(depth_map, cmap='viridis')
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.title('Depth Map')
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in plot_depth_map: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

def depth_map_to_point_cloud(depth_map):
    try:
        height, width = depth_map.shape
        points = []
        for v in range(height):
            for u in range(width):
                z = depth_map[v, u]
                if z > 0:  # Depth value should be positive
                    x = u
                    y = v
                    points.append([x, y, z])

        points = np.array(points)
        print(f"Number of valid points: {len(points)}")
        if len(points) == 0:
            raise ValueError("No valid points found to create point cloud.")

        point_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
        point_cloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
        return point_cloud

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in depth_map_to_point_cloud: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

def point_cloud_to_mesh(point_cloud):
    alpha = 0.1
    mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_alpha_shape(point_cloud, alpha)
    return mesh

def save_mesh(mesh, file_path):
    print(f"Saving mesh to {file_path}")
    try:
        dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_path)
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.makedirs(dir_name)

        o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh(file_path, mesh)
        print("Mesh saved successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in save_mesh: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise

def main():
    file_path = './dataset/mini6.ply'
    output_file_dir = './output/'

    width, height = 640, 480

    try:
        ply = read_point_cloud(file_path)

        points = np.asarray(ply.points)
        depth_map = generate_depth_map(points, width, height)
        refined_depth_map = refine_depth_map(depth_map)

        depth_point_cloud = depth_map_to_point_cloud(refined_depth_map)

        mesh = point_cloud_to_mesh(depth_point_cloud)

        if not os.path.exists(output_file_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_file_dir)

        output_file = os.path.join(output_file_dir, "output_mesh.ply")
        save_mesh(mesh, output_file)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Bir hata oluştu: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Problem I'm Having:
I can successfully create the point cloud, but even though the point_cloud_to_mesh function indicates that it has created the mesh, I have a problem when I try to save the created mesh. Where the mesh should be saved, nothing is saved or it looks like the mesh was not created.
Error Messages:
I don't get any error messages during mesh creation, but when I call the save_mesh function the mesh file is not saved.
Question:
Am I making a mistake in the mesh creation or saving part of my code? Do you have any suggestions on this?
I am not sure if I am using the create_from_point_cloud_alpha_shape function correctly. Is the Alpha value appropriate in this case?
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you. ❤️

Difficult to know what's going on without knowing what your pointcloud looks like, but my guess would be that your alpha value is too small to generate an enveloppe so you're trying to save an empty mesh.
What does this do?
saved = o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh(file_path, mesh, print_progress=True)
if saved:
    print("Mesh saved successfully")
else:
    print("Something went wrong")


